# How to solve "Tag is not NDEF-compliant" in .Net Maui Plugin.NFC?

Tags: nfc, maui

I'm using Plugin.NFC in a .Net Maui 7 app.

I'm trying to write some NFC cards using the provided code on [GitHub](https://github.com/franckbour/Plugin.NFC).

The code works properly, but Whenever I use a new card, when trying to write something on it, I'm getting the error:

> Tag is not NDEF-compliant.

Here is my code :

```
async Task Publish()
{               
    try
    {     
        CrossNFC.Current.StartPublishing(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await RaiseError(ex.Message);
    }
}

async void Current_OnTagDiscovered(ITagInfo tagInfo, bool format)
{
    if (!CrossNFC.Current.IsWritingTagSupported)
    {
        await RaiseMessage_("Writing cards is not supported by your device");
        return;
    }
    
    try
    {
        NFCNdefRecord record;

        record = new NFCNdefRecord
        {
            TypeFormat = NFCNdefTypeFormat.Mime,
            MimeType = "application/com.companyname.nfcsample",
            Payload = NFCUtils.EncodeToByteArray("Hithere");
        };

        tagInfo.Records = new[] { record };            
        CrossNFC.Current.PublishMessage(tagInfo, false);
        
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        await RaiseError("Writing failed\n" + Ex.Message);            
    }
}
```

I also noticed that this happens **only with new cards**. If I take a card and I write something on it using **NFC Tools** app, then I'm able to write on it using my code. It becomes fully usable on my app.

It seems like there is something I'm missing on the "initialization" of the card. How can I solve this?

Comment: Quite a few NFC Tag types need Tags to be formatted to be able write Ndef Data to them, this is basically configuring them to store Ndef data. e.g on a Type 2 Tag this is usually just writing the correct TLV blocks to the memory area. You don't specify the Tag hardware make and model you are using so it is difficult to answer. On Android it has some built in formatting methods with the NdefFormattable class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NdefFormatable, ios is more manual but I don't know how this Plugin handles formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The new card need the tags to write the NDEF data. So the new card must make a initialization.

The project also provided some information [iOS Considerations](https://github.com/franckbour/Plugin.NFC#ios-considerations) about the new card.

- A Mifare Classic 1K card will scan if there is a valid NDEF record on
  it. A blank card will not scan.

For Android:

- The procedures to convert unformated tags to NDEF
  formatted tags are not specified by NFC Forum, and are not generally
  well-known. So there is no mandatory set of tags for which all
  Android devices with NFC must support `NdefFormatable`.